# Drupal 7 change submit for _form_user_pass_alter()

Tags: 7, forms, users

I'd like to change the submission function for TEMPLATE_form_user_pass_alter()

```
function TEMPLATE_form_user_pass_alter($form, &$form_state) {
  $form['#submit'][0] = 'new_user_pass_submit';
}
```

This changes the value in $form, but it still will not submit using the new function.

Do I have to treat this password reset differently than other forms?

My ultimate goal is to send different emails for password resets based on the user's role,and if anyone has any better ideas I'd love to hear them!

Comment: You must replace TEMPLATE with the technical name of your module. And just if you haven't done: Enable the module and clear the caches.

Comment: I've got this in template.php , with the appropriate template name.

Comment: I have decided to make use of hook_mail_alter instead, $message["params"]->account contains the user account that is being reset.

Comment: You can not call hook_form_alter in template.php. It's supposed to be implemented in a (custom) module.

Comment: you definitely can hook there (I've done it, multiple times), is there documentation that says I shouldn't?  


I'm still relatively new to Drupal, but it seems odd that I'd create a module for something very specific to the site that would never work anywhere else.